# why is antimalware service executable taking ram

Tags: windows-10, memory, anti-malware

I am using Windows 10 recently from some one week I am absorbing that the antimalware service executable is taking 10-20% of my ram and i have 8gb ram
I am not getting to know how to stop it

[this is what i see in task manager](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FD5x.png)

Comment: I haven't used W10 in a while, but I believe 100mb is satisfactory and does not consume 10-20% of your RAM.

Comment: no now it is less but when i open the laptop it will be 10% change

Comment: It's understandable that ram usage spikes during startup, but it returns to normal after a few minutes.

Answer (score -2):

So, Antimalware Service Executable can take up to 40-50% of your RAM and it's a legitimate Windows service, and you can't do much about it to get rid of it.
Hovewer, you can try to DISABLE *Real Time Protection*.

To do so: Go to *Settings* > *Update & security* > click on *Windows Security* (left). In the right-pane, scroll down and click on *Virus & threat protection*.

On the next screen, click *Manage Settings* option. Here turn off Real-time protection.

Let me know if works.
Cheers